# Changing default save/load directory

Tags: scripts, python, directory, cron, redirect

I'm writing python scripts in pycharm. When I run them from pycharm, the files that they write are saved in their directory. When I run scripts from terminal using the command

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/***/script.py
```

they save files to my home directory. Also when I use crontab, the files are saved in my home. Can I do something in Ubuntu (without changing the scripts themselves) to force executed scripts to save files in the same directory as the script? I bet that this is related to stdout, but stdout redirect works for console output.

Comment: You can do `/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/***/script.py > /home/user/***/`

Comment: It show this:
bash: /home/artem/PycharmProjects/: Is a directory